# Details not displaying on template page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to get details of a single record to display on a template page with Django, but I can't see anything

My urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from calendarapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('flight/<int:pk>', views.details, name='details'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Flight

def index(request):

    flights = Flight.objects.all()[:5]

    return render(request, 'calendarapp/index.html', {'flights': flights})

def details(request, pk):

    flight = Flight.objects.get(id=pk)

    return render(request, 'calendarapp/index.html', {'flight': flight})
```

My template page

```
{% extends 'calendarapp/base.html' %}

<div class='container'>
  {% block content %}
    <p>departure time - {{ id.dep_time }}</p>
    <p>departure delay - {{ flight.dep_delay }}</p>
    <p>arrival time - {{ flight.arr_time }}</p>
    <p>arrival delay - {{ flight.arr_delay }}</p>
    <p>cancelled - {{ flight.cancelled }}</p>
    <p>carrier - {{ flight.carrier }}</p>
    <p>tail number - {{ flight.tailnum }}</p>
    <p>flight - {{ flight.flight }}</p>
    <p>origin - {{ flight.origin }}</p>
    <p>destination - {{ flight.dest }}</p>
    <p>air time - {{ flight.air_time }}</p>
    <p>distance - {{ flight.distance }} km</p>
    <p>duration - {{ flight.duration }}</p>
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

I'm not sure why my details are not displaying?

Comment: index and details have the same templates, are you sure your URL calls the right view?

Comment: That's great :D